# Jquery chosen не работает автодополнение с кириллицей

Tags: jquery

Хочу вывести выпадающий список, и прикрутить плагин chosen к нему.

Но почему то не работает автодополнение , если варианты на русском языке.

html

```
<select  data-placeholder="" id="list"  class="noStyle" style="display: none">
     <option>Мед</option>
     <option>Мед</option>
     <option>Snoop Dog</option>
      <option>Медведь</option>
    </select>
```

js

```
$("#list").chosen();
```

Если слово на латинице то ищет нормально, скрин http://prntscr.com/es6tux но если кириллица то http://prntscr.com/es6u3x в чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 2):

Вообщем я попробовал взять с одного из своих проектов код плагина  Chosen версии 1.4.2 и у меня заработал список, все слова ищутся корректно. А сперва пытался использовать последнюю версию 1.7.0 , возможно в новой версии есть какой то баг. Т.к даже в демо файле плагина не работает кириллица.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать `search_contains: true` - тогда работает